# Install "balance" on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I used Cygwin's `setup-x86_64.exe` program to install several packages including `balance`. The other packages installed correctly, but `balance` seems to be incorrectly installed. There is no `balance.exe` anywhere on my computer, but I can read the manual by typing `man balance`.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the package, but the result was the same.

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know why it didn't install properly?
2. Is there a work-around to install it manually. I can see where `balance-3.54-1.tar.bz2` was downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking in the right directory ?
Programs under `/usr/sbin` are by default not in the PATH

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/balance/balance-3.54-1

```
balance: TCP load-balancing proxy server (installed binaries and support files)

    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/lib/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/sbin/
    2013-04-28 12:58       32275 usr/sbin/balance.exe
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/share/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/share/doc/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/share/doc/balance/
    2013-04-28 12:58       15095 usr/share/doc/balance/COPYING
    2013-04-28 12:58         684 usr/share/doc/balance/README
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/share/doc/Cygwin/
    2013-04-28 12:58        1997 usr/share/doc/Cygwin/balance.README
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/share/man/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 usr/share/man/man1/
    2013-04-28 12:58        3624 usr/share/man/man1/balance.1.gz
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 var/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 var/run/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 var/run/balance/
    2013-04-28 12:58           0 var/run/balance/.keep-balance
```

you can also use:

```
cygcheck -l balance
```

and

```
cygcheck -c balance
```

for veryfing the content and status of a package